# webpack not working when introducing routes on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

I am using webpack 4 to automate some tasks for my web app.

Page shows blank on production mode, when running command: **npm run build**

it works with **npm run start** all good. The thing is webpack is not being able somehow to deal with this part:

```
<BrowserRouter><AppRoutes/></BrowserRouter>
```

And my index.js looks as:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './routes';
require('../src/assets/styles/main.scss');
console.log("I am being called index.js...");
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><AppRoutes/></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("index"));
```

while webpack looks like:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log("ENV DETECTED: " + argv.mode);
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "html-loader",
                            options: {
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        // 'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                config: {
                                    path: './postcss.config.js'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        argv.mode !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                config: {
                                    path: './postcss.config.js'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {}),
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./src/index.html",
                filename: "./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "main.css",
                chunkFilename: "[id].css"
            }),
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ]
    }
};
```

I dont know why on production the app is not showing the components at all!

ANy help on this?

Edited:

My routes.js looks as following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Helloworld from './components/helloworld/helloworld.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from "./components/thirdview/thirdview.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview/:number' component={ThirdView}/>
        </Switch>
    </main>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

if I change `<Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/>` to `<Route path='/' component={Helloworld}/>` it works, but then I have problem navigation to other components, somehow my page url is different when I open the index.html on production mode.

The error I get when trying to navigate from helloworld component(after removing exact from Route tag) to secondview component is :

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history
>   state object with URL 'file:///secondview' cannot be created in a
>   document with origin 'null' and URL
>   'file:///home/webapp/Desktop/myapp/dist/index.html'.

Comment: basically helloworld component is not being called at one on prod mode

Comment: if I change <Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/> to <Route  path='/' component={Helloworld}/> it works, but then I have problem navigation to other components, somehow my page url is different when I open the index.html on production mode.

Comment: Any console logs or error messages when you open in prod mode?

Comment: @SteveBanton look the edited section to my question!

Comment: I think the problem may be that you need to serve your index.html with a server, so the react router receives path. Please see my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

### Serve App With Express

Basically, when you change paths you are moving away from your index.html unless you serve the react app with a server of some kind. Try to setup an express server for index with something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

// serve static assets eg. js and css files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// Handles all routes
app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

You can put this in your root directory as server.js, make sure index is being referred to in the sendFile line (right now assumes index.html is in /public directory), run this with `babel-node server.js`, and should serve your app on localhost:3000.

Comment: I think you are right, I need to run index.html on a  server! WIll try this!

Comment: working thnx, also do u have any idea that I can somehow configure routes work with the urls when opening index.html directly without any server.

Comment: no problem. I don't think it can work that way. Think of it this way - browser is accessing `file:///home/webapp/Desktop/myapp/dist/` in your file tree to get index.html. If you try to change the url to `file:///home/webapp/Desktop/myapp/dist/second/` by pushing to route, what is it going to access? What if that folder doesn't exist in your file tree (which it probably doesn't)? You need a server that will handle all routes and pass them to router.

Comment: it didnt work actually, i tried to add into a web server in ubuntu var/www/html  the dist folder and tried to access from browser, so still i see an empty page, so basically the helloworld comopnent is not showing up! not called at all!

Comment: I am now all confused, how can I make this work, do I have to fire a server specifically for my routes? if so how to use the dist folder to serve my page as that is the minified one!

Comment: you have to use a server to serve your bundled js, css and html file. That's the express.static line above. Then, handle routes with a wildcard - that's the app.get('*' line, which directs all routes eg. `localhost:3000/second/` to index.html. Here, js, css and html files would be in /public relative to the location of server.js. As long as it can find your files, should work.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error running this server? Why did you think it worked before?